# SQL command to update column value in table

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

Following is code on `python manage shell`

```
>>> User.objects.filter(email__icontains="gmail.com").values_list("email", flat=True)
[u'abc@gmail.com', u'vivekbsable@gmail.com', u'vivek@gmail.com', u'xyz@gmail.com', u'vivekbsable@gmail.com']
>>> for ii in User.objects.filter(email__icontains="gmail.com"):
...      ii.email = ii.email.replace("@gmail.com", "@custom.com")
...      ii.save() 
...     
... 
>>> User.objects.filter(email__icontains="gmail.com").values_list("email", flat=True)
[]
>>> User.objects.filter(email__icontains="@custom.com").values_list("email", flat=True)
[u'vivek@custom.com', u'xyz@custom.com', u'abc@custom.com', u'vivekbsable@custom.com', u'vivekbsable@custom.com']
>>>
```

I want to write SQL command in Postgresql terminal (`python manage dbshell`)

How can I convert above in **SQL command**?

Following are my try:

**[Edited1]**:

Get Target email ids by SQL command:

```
dp=# SELECT  email FROM auth_user where email LIKE '%@gmail.com';
           email           
---------------------------
 vivek@gmail.com
 xyz@gmail.com
 abc@gmail.com
 vivekbsable@gmail.com
 vivekbsable@gmail.com
(5 rows)

dp=#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to replace domain in emails, here is test select:

```
select email, replace(email, '@gmail.com', '@custom.com') as new_email 
from auth_user 
where email like '%@gmail.com';
```

And update will be:

```
update auth_user 
set email = replace(email, '@gmail.com', '@custom.com') 
where email like '%@gmail.com';
```

Comment: @Thank you, Up-voted. I add my answer too can you review my answer?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I convert above in SQL command?

You can have a look at the query Django generates for this, it might not be runnable as in (e.g. missing params that are sent by Django), but it'll give you a good idea of how Django translates it to SQL

The idea is to print this value: `Model.objects.filter(...).values_list(...).query`

```
query = User.objects.filter(email__icontains="@custom.com").values_list("email", flat=True).query

# Make it print it
print query 
print(query) # Python 3 or with "from future import print_function"
```

Comment: Thank you, Up-voted. I add my answer too can you review by answer?

Answer (score 0):

Following is my solution:

```
UPDATE auth_user Set email = replace(email, '@gmail.com', '@custom.com') where email LIKE '%@gmail.com';
```

**Demo:**

Go into dbshell
1. cd /var/op/project_name
   `python manage dbshell`

```
dp=# SELECT  email FROM auth_user where email LIKE '%@gmail.com';
           email           
---------------------------
 vivek@gmail.com
 xyz@gmail.com
 abc@gmail.com
 vivekbsable@gmail.com
 vivekbsable@gmail.com
(5 rows)

dp=# SELECT  email FROM auth_user where email LIKE '%@custom.com';
 email 
-------
(0 rows)

dp=# UPDATE auth_user Set email = replace(email, '@gmail.com', '@custom.com') where email LIKE '%@gmail.com';
UPDATE 5

dp=# SELECT  email FROM auth_user where email LIKE '%@gmail.com';
 email 
-------
(0 rows)

dp=# SELECT  email FROM auth_user where email LIKE '%@custom.com';
           email            
----------------------------
 vivek@custom.com
 xyz@custom.com
 abc@custom.com
 vivekbsable@custom.com
 vivekbsable@custom.com
(5 rows)

dp=#
```